# Select2: using bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I have the below code. It works but the input is small. I want it to look like any other Bootstrap input, ie. to fill the entire div container. I have installed the Bootstrap theme. I tryed to use .form-control class.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <select class="states" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".states").select2({
    theme: "bootstrap"
  });
});
```

Comment: Would you present a screenshot of the outputted HTML?

Comment: Please add jsfiddle link too if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use css 
`.states{ width:100%; }`

```css
.row {
  background-color:lightgray;
}

.states{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-md-6">
    <select class="states" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```